# Is it possible to change image filename in every page?

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

I have a website which is used for ads listings like backpage and craigslist.

I have inserted a Banner Ad on every sidebar on every city: for example the banner image filename is

```
myimage.jpg
```

now what I want to happen is: whenever they visit a city (for example *mysite.com/boston*), I want the filename to be like this:

```
src="myimage-boston.jpg"
```

and when they visit

```
mysite.com/birmingham
```

the image filename will be

```
src="myimage-birmingham.jpg"
```

I'm doing this for SEO purposes. I hope I've explained it well. Thank you in advance :) btw im using codeigniter.

Comment: I doubt whether this will have a real world SEO effect. Do you have reliable information that it will? What it *will* do is hinder cacheability if a user switches cities, forcing the browser to reload the image even if it is the same

Comment: im just following task from my boss :), nope im not planning to duplicate the images file, just 1 single image.

Comment: Well, fair enough I guess... although your boss should really rethink this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googlebot couldn't crawl this URL because it points to a non-existent page. Generally, 404s don't harm your site's performance in search, but you can use them to help improve the user experience.

Comment: Not true: the URL may not be physically existent file. If it doesn't exist, server may decide to place other contents and return HTTP 200 OK header. The client (including Googlebot) can not find out that the file physically doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [mod-rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), try this rewrite rule in Apache server config `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf` (if you have images in `/images` path):

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)-.*\.jpg$ /images/$1.jpg
```

After that, you can substitute image src for anything you want:

```
<img src="/images/<?=$imageName."-".$whateverYouWant.".".jpg";?>" />
```

And the rewrite module will substitute it for `/images/$imageName.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `__CLASS__` magic constant to your view, and you should know wich controler is being called.

more info here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

its should look like something like this:

`$mydata['class'] = strtolower(__CLASS__);`

and on your view

`src="myimage-<?php echo $class; ?>.jpg"`

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple, use javascript. U can access the URL via document.location. Then say detect the name of city using regex or substring and create image name dynamically.

This can also be done on the server side. But Javascript is better for a job like this.

Comment: OP stated he's doing it for SEO purposes. [Not even Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) will parse your javascript this way. Meaning, the links will remain untouched to the crawler... and his SEO dreams will be shattered.